# Why does Float16(1.1)-Float16(1)=Float16(0.0996)?

Tags: julia

I am trying to compute by hand `Float16(1.1)-Float16(1)`. Since Float16 allows 10 bits for the fraction, when I do the subtraction by hand with  10 bits precision I do not get 0.0996.

Can someone step me through how to do this subtraction using the bits?

Comment: Are you remembering the implicit bit?

Comment: @OscarSmith Ahhhhh, I was, thank you very much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems the comments have already answered your question, but for anyone else it may be useful to add that you can easily inspect the actual bit patterns with `bitstring` to see what is going on in such cases:

```
julia> bitstring(Float16(1.1))
"0011110001100110"

julia> bitstring(Float16(1.0))
"0011110000000000"

julia> bitstring(Float16(1.1)-Float16(1.0))
"0010111001100000"
```

where the bits are divided as follows

[image: IEEE 754 half-precision format]

For reference, the "implicit bit" referenced in the comments is explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_half-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary16)

> The format is assumed to have an implicit lead bit with value 1 unless the exponent field is stored with all zeros. Thus only 10 bits of the significand appear in the memory format but the total precision is 11 bits.

Comment: Here is the formula to convert pieces of the bit string back to Float16 in case it helps anyone else: `Float16(-1)^Float16(0b0) * Float16(2)^(Float16(0b01011)-Float16(15)) * (Float16(1) + Float16(0b1001100000) / Float16(1024))` => `Float16(0.0996)`

Comment: Great reference: https://ryanstutorials.net/binary-tutorial/binary-floating-point.php

Comment: That's a nice one!